# PySide: Making a QGraphicsItem only ignore size transformations

Tags: scale, pyside, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I've  got a `QGraphicsItem` I'm using as a cornergrabber for resizing another object. But when I call `scale()` on the `QGraphicsView` containing it, the size of the `QGraphicsItem` changes as well. As a cornergrabber, I want the size to be consistent throughout all zoom levels, but keep the positioning the same.

Is this possible? Setting the `ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag makes the item position ignore the position as well as the size.

I'm on Python 3.3.2 and PySide 1.2.1.